# Why doesn't python use its own argparse library for its associated --hhelp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

(**Note**: The title cannot have the word 'help' in it, so intentionally misspelled).

The python module has [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to pass command-line arguments. However, when I look at python itself, and doing:

```
$ python -h
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables):
-b     : issue warnings about str(bytes_instance), str(bytearray_instance)
         and comparing bytes/bytearray with str. (-bb: issue errors)
-B     : don't write .pyc files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
...
```

It seems to be using [`initconfig.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8f42748ded5e978fe8a924115179d45a74a6363b/Python/initconfig.c). Why does it use this and not its own library? Is this for backwards compatibility or why are the cmdline args passed/interpreted there?

Comment: counterpoint, why _should_ it use its own `argparse` library? It was only introduced into the python standard library around version 2.7/3.2, and prior to that python still had to write its `--help` command-line text. Why change what isn't broken?

Comment: My guess would be that its a chicken/egg problem. How would it call the interpreted argparse Python code before starting the Python interpreter?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy good point.

Comment: Python also has `getopt` and `optparse` libraries.  Scripts (other than the main interpreter) that originally used `optparse` have mostly been ported to `argparse`.